sp_send_dbmail fails when query is included
I am running SQL Server 2022 Enterprise inside a company domain.  I have a SQL Agent job that runs a stored procedure.  The job runs under a domain account say 'domain\myuser' that is a member of 'sysadmin' on this sql server.  It's also the same account that runs SQL Server Agent service.
When I manually run this job under SQL Server Agent in SSMS, I get this error whenever the @query parameter is supplied.

Executed as user: domain\myuser. Failed to initialize sqlcmd library
with error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050).

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'my_profile',           
    @recipients = 'myemail@xyz.com',    
    @subject = 'Test Send',
    @query = 'SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.backupfile WHERE 1=0';

If I simply remove @query, it works fine.  If I include the @query but logged into SSMS as 'sa' and execute the SP in SSMS, it also works fine.  It fails with that error when it's run as an agent job.
I have spent almost the entire day searching and reading but haven't been able to find a solution.
Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong or what other permissions might be needed?
Thanks

Can you run the query directly as domain\myuser?

Does domain\myuser have the sysadmin explicitly granted or is he a member of group which has sysadmin rights?

What if you change the job owner to sa? Also, what if you expicitly login to windows as the Agent account and run that code? Those two tests should give you further info for troubleshooting.

If I run the SP in SSMS logged in as 'domain\myuser', it fails with the same error.  I already granted this 'domain\myuser' to be member of SYSADMIN.  The job was created  by 'sa' so the owner is 'sa'.  I have already tried all those suggestions in above but none fixed the issue.  This is why it's baffling to me.   Does sp_send_dbmail need specific permissions?

What's the difference between the built-in 'sa' vs. creating a SQL login (ex: sa2) and granting 'sa2' to be a member of 'SYSADMIN'?  For now, the only way I get it to work is the execute the SP as 'sa' in SSMS.  If I execute it as 'sa2', it would fail with various errors.  I can't remember exactly now since I was testing so many different things yesterday.   I have a feeling 'sa' can do much more under the hood than 'sa2' in terms privileges.

What does the error actually mean as posted in my original question?

I found this documentation from Microsoft today:
--
A query to execute. The results of the query can be attached as a file, or included in the body of the e-mail message.
The query is of type nvarchar(max), and can contain any valid Transact-SQL statements. The query is executed in a
separate session, so local variables in the script calling sp_send_dbmail aren't available to the query.
Now i'm wondering what credential it's using in the separate session??

See if this is of any help: SQL Server Management Send Mail as Part of a Job. Also, what is the type chosen on the job step configuration?

Ronaldo, as suggested in your link to use a simple query to rule out other things, I get the same error when I simply replaced my @query to be like this:
query = 'SELECT 1;'

Your error says "Failed to initialize sqlcmd library" is the type of your job step "Operating System (CmdExec)" or "Transact-SQL Script (T-SQL)"? Where you able to config the XE session to capture any other error involved? Is SQLCMD installed and working on that server (can you connect to SQL Server using it)?

The job step runs a SP which calls msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail.  I posted it this snippet of code in my original post in above.  The "sqlcmd.exe' utility works fine.  I tested it at the command proompt.  In fact, this is how I currently workaround this issue.  I have a Windows Task that runs this failing SP but this job runs under the 'sa' account.   Here's the real question then:  does sp_send_dbmail invokes any type of .exe or .dll related to SQLCMD?

Whenever I include the @query param, it fails with that error.  The tsql can be as simple as "SELECT 1" as I already mentioned, it fails.  If I remove this param, I get the email.
